# Datatables - no data available in table even tough there is data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I created a page where some data is being received via a websocket connection and is shown on a Datatables table. Here is what the data looks like:

```
var data = [
[1, 5],
[9, 3],
[71.55, 17],
[1800, 20],
[713, 3],
]
```

Every second, i receive an array like that, just with different data. Every time a new array is received, i will show the data on the table and overwrite the old data. To do that i used `table.clear()`.

The problem with my actual code is that, even though the data is showing and i can see it correctly, i keep seeing the error `No data available in table` at the bottom of the table. I know it's not a major issue, but is there any way to remove it, or at least see why it is showing? Here is my code:

```
 ticksSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
    // ......
    var data = [//Here goes the data i receive every second
    ];

    $(document).ready(function() {
      add();
    });

    function add(table) {
      $('#mytable').DataTable().clear().draw();
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        $('#mytable').prepend('<tr><td>'+value[0]+'</td><td>'+value[1]+'</td></tr>')
      })
    }

};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61413296/how-can-i-overwrite-data-on-datatables/61413662#61413662

Comment: Yes! It's the same code and it works without any issue! The only problem is that error showing and i want to find a way to remove it